# jquery table2csv with links

Tags: jquery, csv

I am using table2csv which is a great little plugin, but one issue I am having is to have hyperlinks in my csv, Here is what my table looks like:

```
<table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Province</th>
                            <th>optIn</th>
                            <th>Upload</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                            foreach($returnArray as $key => $value) {
                                $optIn = "";
                                if($value["optIn"] == 0){
                                    $optIn = "No";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $optIn = "Yes";
                                }
                                echo "<tr>
                                <td>" . $value["firstName"] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $value["lastName"] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $value["email"] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $value["city"] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $value["province"] . "</td>
                                <td>" . $optIn . "</td>";
                                $file = "";
                                if($value["fileUpload"] == "")
                                {
                                    $file = "<td></td>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $file = "<td><a href='../uploads/" . $value["fileUpload"] . "' target='_blank'>View</a></td>";
                                }
                                echo $file . "</tr>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </table>
```

This column has a link in it:

```
<td><a href='../uploads/" . $value["fileUpload"] . "' target='_blank'>View</a></td>
```

How do I get that link to appear in my csv?

Here is the jquery code:

```
let options = {
                        "separator": ",",
                        "newline": "\n",
                        "quoteFields": true,
                        "excludeColumns": "",
                        "excludeRows": "",
                        "trimContent": true,
                        "filename": "table.csv",
                        "appendTo": "#output"
                    }

                    $('.table').table2csv('download', options);
```

Comment: Plugin doesn't interpret HTML content within the table cells, including the hyperlinks.